# Connect and send data from Android device to computer with Bluetooth?

Tags: android, sdk, bluetooth

Is there some way I can send data from an Android device to a computer over Bluetooth?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Perhaps the most straightforward way to get started would be to use the Bluetooth Chat example, which you will hopefully find in the Samples directory of your SDK installation, or can of course be downloaded from Google.

The Bluetooth Chat demonstrates exchanging bytes of data from one Android device to another over the Bluetooth Serial Port Profile (SPP).

To exchange data between the Android device and your computer, you could use a Bluetooth driver on your computer that provides you with a virtual COM port when a remote Bluetooth SPP device connects. This way, you could simply launch Bluetooth Chat on your Android device, and exchange data with something that reads and writes to a COM port on your computer. For example, on a Windows machine you could simply use HyperTerminal.

The Bluetooth Chat example is then an excellent base upon which to create your own custom Bluetooth Android application.